# The structure of txt file code is reading from

Tags: java, file-io

can anybody please explain why there have to be exactly 3 empty rows in between sections of text (marked with number) in the txt file my code is reading from ?

I have a code that is reading lines from txt file. The structure of the file is as follows:

1 
r
line of text
line of text
line of text
line of text
line of text



2 
a
line of text
line of text
line of text
line of text
line of text

A number is a mark that i m using to identify which section to read. When section is identified my code then reads consecutive lines of text and returned values are assigned to String variables.
All works perfectly only and only if there is exactly 3 empty rows separating each section of text is source txt file. I d like to understand why is it so ? Thank you very much

Here's the snippet of my code:

```
inpStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resources/myFile.txt");
try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inpStream,"UTF-16BE"))){           
       do{
           num = Integer.toString(a);
           line = reader.readLine();                             
           if(line.equals(num)){
             who = reader.readLine(); 
             what = reader.readLine();
             sat = reader.readLine();
             pow = reader.readLine();
             satNo = reader.readLine();
             cash = reader.readLine();
             break;
         }     
     } while(!line.equals(num) && (line = reader.readLine()) != null );
   }
   catch(IOException e){}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the number and order of calls to readLine().

Your code reads and checks every other line for a match. The three blank lines are not important, it's just that it's an even number since the first index number. It will also work with one, five etc.

The double read occurs once at the beginning of each iteration, and once in the condition.

```
line = reader.readLine();
```

and

```
while(... && (line = reader.readLine()) != null
```

Thereby skipping two lines each iteration.

I would recommend either moving the first read out of the loop, or change to a while-loop:

```
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine() != null) {
    if (line.equals(num){
        ...
        break;
    }
}
```

This reads each line, checking against num for each line.

Defining `num` can also be moved out of the loop, as it does not change inside the loop. Giving a full example of:

```
InputStream inpStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resources/myFile.txt");
try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inpStream, "UTF-8"))) {

    num = Integer.toString(a);

    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

        if (line.equals(num)) {
            who = reader.readLine();
            what = reader.readLine();
            sat = reader.readLine();
            pow = reader.readLine();
            satNo = reader.readLine();
            cash = reader.readLine();
            break;
        }
    }

} catch (IOException e) {
}
```

Note: This example uses UTF-8.

Comment: Thank you starf for explaining. I couldnt figure out, what a shame :-) I reworked it as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You have to read all the lines whether you need them or not.  You can't pretend you read lines, that you didn't.  You can skip the lines after the ones you needed.

Answer (score 0):

Lets break up your code line by line and analyze.

#### Line 1.

You call the [getClass()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/class/classNew.html) function on an InputStream object which in turn you use to call the [getStreamResource()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)) function to return a "stream" to your file data.

Now having access to this stream you enclose your BufferReader in a try/catch statement.

#### Line2.

next you create a [BufferReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) with Reader Parameter inpstream and file encoding type UFT-16.

#### Line 3-13

You haven't shown me where you have declared 'a' so I can't be sure, but you are converting an integer 'a' to a string called num. (This is important because it is the terminating factor of your do statement.) I am assuming a =1 in the first iteration.

Now its all about understanding File Offsets.
when you say

`line=reader.readLine();`

this returns a String containing the current line characters and sets the file offset to the next line.

your file offset is at 'r' (for 1st iteration).

The same technique for reading who,what,sat,pow,satNo & cash.

Now your while statement checks if both conditions are true or not. i.e line != num (which it is since you haven't redefined num anywhere after reading who,what,sat,pow,satNo & cash.) And also line=line.readLine() != null which is also true.

However here is your first mistake calling `line=reader.readLine()` the way you did this  increments the file offset one more line. Thus in two iterations two lines are read in addition to what you expect. This messes up the order in which you envisioned your variables to be found i.e who,what,sat,pow,satNo & cash etc in your do statement.

Therefore in short you are skipping every other line after your first iteration.
You need to get rid of one of your readLine calls.

The two double counting are:

`line = inpstream.readLine()` and

```
line = reader.readLine()) != null
```

Comment: No worries. If you liked the answer please upvote and accept.